# Java input in Clojure with (read-line) not reading properly in Emacs

Tags: java, emacs, clojure, swank

Has anyone encountered a problem with emacs on windows and java input ? (read-line) in the REPL does not recognise the delimiter (well thats my guess).

Using a vanilla clojure in the box, same issue.

Further clarification.

Using (read-line) or the scanner class within the REPL in EMACS
the reader will not respond to return (As in it will just go down to the next line rather then read the input).

(edit)

The read-line works in inferior lisp buffer but not the swank clojure buffer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.  http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/f4947ed97574a677 may be relevant?

Answer (score 2):

This is a (I suppose?) known bug. I'll see what Phil has to say.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using the emacs starter kit with slime, all of which can be downloaded from => http://technomancy.us/126.